# Have scrollbar appear on website only if height shortened so text cuts off

Tags: css, responsive-design, height, responsive

I don't know if this is possible, but I'll ask. I have a website that has five pages. Each page is contained within an `article` tag. Here is the CSS for the `article` tag:

```
article {
    padding-top: 10vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: fixed;
    padding-left: 20vw;
    padding-right: 20vw;
    top: 0;
    left: -100vw;
    transition: left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I don't think any of the HTML or other CSS is relevant, but I can provide it if you think it is.

Anyway, each page has a different amount of content. The `article`s have a height of `100vh` and are set up not to have a scrollbar, which is how I want the site normally. And each `article` has a different amount of HTML content and therefore a different amount of space below the content.

The issue is that if someone adjusts the height to make the window shorter, then content can get cut off. The amount of adjustment required to do this differs from page to page because of the differing amount of content.

I am wondering if it is possible not to have a scrollbar when the height allows for all the content to be visible but then have a scrollbar appear once the height reduction causes the content to be cut off. If it is possible I am wondering if it is also possible to have this occur at different heights depending on the content for each page. Finally, I am wondering if it is possible to have it set up "automatically" so that if you change the content of a page it will then change when the scrollbar appears.

I thought about overflow:scroll, but when I tried it the scrollbar appeared even when there was no cutoff.

I am looking for any and all advice on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to use `overflow:auto` instead of `overflow:scroll`. Check it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: Perfect! That got me what I needed! Thanks!